# Do you use a dedicated JIRA issue for adding Unit tests and "Cosmetic" changes?

Tags: unit-testing, jira

I recall seeing before in some projects a well-known JIRA issue that would be linked to all new Unit test and "Cosmetic" commits. Is this a common practice? Are there cons I could overlook? I kind of like this approach because e.g. all commits will have an associated JIRA issue and creating one JIRA issue for every new Unit test or even Suite seems excessive.

Comment: Should this question be in project mgmt forum instead?

Comment: I find it too technical to be at the PM level.

Comment: There is Programmers Stack Exchange for conceptual questions like this. It describes itself as "Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a JIRA issue for pieces of work that can happen in parallel. So if multiple people are working on unit tests, create an issue for each unit test, or group of unit tests. The question of creating an issue for cosmetic changes usually arises because someone declares that every commit must have a JIRA issue key in its message. It's usually better to only require that on the most important branches or trunk/master so people don't have to work around the policy

Answer (score 1):

I can not tell you, if that is a common practice.

I think it is bad, to add all JUnit Tests and Cosmetics as a sub-task to one Task.

Lets say, u got a Structure like this:

---

- Common User Story
- Tasks

  - Task1
  - Task2
  - Task3
- Cosmetic and Junit Container

  - Cosmetic
  - JUnit

---

Then you will not be able to check (easily), if the Tasks1 JUnit Test was completed or not.

If you do it like that

---

- Common User Story

  - Tasks

    - Task1

      - Cosmetic
      - JUnit
    - Task2

      - Cosmetic
    - Task3

      - JUnit

---

you can easily check, what Cosmetics regard to what Task, what Junit test, of that task is completed and which not, also better for time tracking etc.